# Corda Unknown entity error when running NodeDriver test with QueryableState in java

Tags: corda

When running a NodeDriver test that uses a QueryableState, I get an error saying "Unknown entity". I confirmed that if I remove the QueryableState code from the State, the tests run successfully.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
>   com.template.states.IOUCustomSchema$PersistentIOU

Here is the implementation of the QueryableState:

```
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract.class)
public class IOUState implements ContractState, LinearState, QueryableState {

    public final Amount<TokenType> amount;
    public final Party lender;
    public final Party borrower;
    public final Amount<TokenType> paid;
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;

    // Private constructor used only for copying a State object
    @ConstructorForDeserialization
    private IOUState(Amount<TokenType> amount, Party lender, Party borrower, Amount<TokenType> paid, UniqueIdentifier linearId){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.lender = lender;
        this.borrower = borrower;
        this.paid = paid;
        this.linearId = linearId;
    }

    public IOUState(Amount<TokenType> amount, Party lender, Party borrower) {
        this(amount, lender, borrower, new Amount<>(0, amount.getToken()), new UniqueIdentifier());
    }

    /** omitting boiletplate */

    /**
     *  This method will return a list of the nodes which can "use" this state in a valid transaction. In this case, the
     *  lender or the borrower.
     */
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return ImmutableList.of(lender, borrower);
    }

    @Override
    public PersistentState generateMappedObject(MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof IOUCustomSchema) {
            return new IOUCustomSchema.PersistentIOU(linearId.getId(), lender.getName().toString(),
                    borrower.getName().toString(), amount.getQuantity());
        } else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema " + schema);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<MappedSchema> supportedSchemas() {
        return ImmutableList.of(new IOUCustomSchema());
    }
}
```

IOUCustomSchema

```
public class IOUCustomSchema extends MappedSchema {

    public IOUCustomSchema() {
        super(IOUCustomSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentState.class));
    }

    @Entity
    @Table
    public static class PersistentIOU extends PersistentState {
        @Column(nullable = false)
        UUID linearId;
        @Column(nullable = false) String lender;
        @Column(nullable = false) String borrower;
        @Column(nullable = false) Long amount;

        public PersistentIOU(UUID linearId, String lender, String borrower, Long amount) {
            this.linearId = linearId;
            this.lender = lender;
            this.borrower = borrower;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public PersistentIOU() {
            this.linearId = null;
            this.lender = null;
            this.borrower = null;
            this.amount = 0L;
        }

        public UUID getLinearId() {
            return linearId;
        }

        public String getLender() {
            return lender;
        }

        public String getBorrower() {
            return borrower;
        }

        public Long getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement the custom schema correctly; you're supposed to have at least 2 classes:

1. `IOUCustomSchema` should be just an empty class that represents the family of schemas for IOUState. See here: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/schema/IOUSchema.java
2. Then you create a V1 of the schema, which is what you did but you should rename your class to `IOUCustomSchemaV1`; so in your code:

   a. Rename class to `IOUCustomSchemaV1`.
   b. Rename constructor to `IOUCustomSchemaV1`.
   c. Keep `super(IOUCustomSchema.class...` as it is.
   d. In your state also rename `IOUCustomSchema` to `IOUCustomSchemaV1` in all occurrences.

You can see the correct implementation in the samples repo, under `cordapp-example` project:

1. Family of schemas: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/schema/IOUSchema.java
2. Schema V1: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/schema/IOUSchemaV1.java
3. State: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java

Answer (score 0):

It was actually just a copy and paste error. I needed to change the following line in order to get things working.

```
super(IOUCustomSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentState.class));
```

I was using the generic PersistentState here instead of my custom PersistentIOU

```
super(IOUCustomSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentIOU.class));
```